# jQuery UI effect .on click only firing once

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jQuery UI effect that highlights the text in a DIV on click of a button. I'm using the `.on` method to acheive this and it successfully highlights the DIV on the first click of the button. However if I click the button subsequent times the effect isn't firing.

Is there a simple solution to this or is the `.on click`method not the best way of interacting with jQuery UI effects? Feel like i'm missing something obvious here!

**jQuery code:**

```
 $(function(){
      $('#table').on('click','button', function() {
      $("#counter").effect('highlight', {color:"#333333"}, 1200);
          }); 
  });
```

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/byates/FtjLf/

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle: jsfiddle.net?

Comment: This is the right way to do it, it should work every time. Can you make a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Perhaps you could post your HTML if you are unable to create a fiddle.

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/byates/FtjLf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using jQuery 2.0 and jQuery UI 1.8; it works fine if you switch to `jQuery UI 1.10.3`.

I'm checking what is the minimal jQuery UI version for jQuery 2.0.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/Nhw2k/

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery 1.x to support browsers from IE6

(jQuery 2.x only supports modern browsers)